# ArcPy raster output spills over environment extent by one row and one column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, arcmap, resampling

I'm resampling a raster, and I would like it to line up and match the dimensions of another template raster. For whatever reason, the output of the `Resample_management` function has an added row and column.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env  

# Set file paths
in_raster = "inputRas.tif"
templateRaster = "templateRas.tif"
out_raster = "outRas.tif"

# Set 'Snap raster' and 'Extent' environment variables
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.sa.Raster(templateRaster).extent
arcpy.env.snapRaster = templateRaster

# Get cell size from template raster (which is 1 m)
cellsizeX = arcpy.Describe(templateRaster).children[0].meanCellWidth
cellsizeY = arcpy.Describe(templateRaster).children[0].meanCellHeight
cellsize = str(cellsizeX) + " " + str(cellsizeY)

# Resample input raster
arcpy.Resample_management(in_raster, out_raster, cellsize)

# Print environment extent
print arcpy.env.extent

# Print extent of the output raster
print arcpy.sa.Raster(out_raster).extent
```

The resulting extents:

```
582568 5816053 583282 5816790 NaN NaN NaN NaN
582567 5816053 583282 5816791 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

The function has essentially added one row of cells to the top of the output and one column of cells to the left. Why?

Comment: What was original cell size?

Comment: It was 0.09282 m

Comment: If so, 5 columns and rows were added. Something doesn't match here. Did it reduce number of columns by factor of 2.

Comment: Sorry, the cell size for `templateRaster` was 1 m, and the cell size for `in_raster` (the raster being resampled) was 0.09282. I would expect that `out_raster` would have the same dimensions row/col numbers as `templateRaster` but that's where the extra row and column have appeared.

Comment: Pragmatic approach: convert extent required to polygon and use it to clip the one you don't like. Also result often depends on how you run the script. Results can be different when you ran it from current mxd, catalog or standalone script. Most naughty in my opinion mxd.

Comment: Yeah, I mean it's not something that's too hard to work around. Just wondering if there was some way to apply the function properly

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34085/aligning-two-non-coincident-equi-resolution-raster-grids-in-arcgis-desktop

Comment: Seems like this person ultimately ran into the same problem (i.e.: having one extra row and column). Doesn't seem like he/she found a solution however.